# Why is Elasticsearch rejecting my input as malformed when using a custom date time stamp?

Tags: elasticsearch

ES Version 2.2.1

Below is the Mapping i have created for the testindex

```
    "event_time_utc": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "format": "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
      "type": "date"
```

Below is the Curl command i am using to insert document into the testindex

```
curl -k -XPOST http://10.1.69.191:8080/testindex/logs -d '{

"Username": "user@mailbox.com",
"Application": "App Dev",
"Platform": "Unknown",
"Browser": "Unknown",
"Status": "Success",
"SourceIP": "1.1.1.1",
"event_time_utc" : "2016-12-08 23:44:40",
"LoginType": "Remote Access 2.0",
"timestamp": "2016-12-12T19:41:36.214Z"
}'
```

Below is the Error being generated by the elasticsearch applications anything it failed to parse the event_time_utc. And giving the malformed date as the reason. But i can't find anything wrong with this.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed 
to parse [event_time_utc]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse
 [event_time_utc]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":
"Invalid format: \"2016-12-08 23:44:40\" is malformed at \" 23:44:40\""}},
```

Answer (score 0):

The date pattern in your mapping is wrong, it should be like below, i.e. you need to encode the space character between two single quotes.

```
"mappings": {
  "logs": {                     <--- make sure you have this
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "event_time_utc": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss",
        "type": "date"
```

Also make sure since you are sending your curl to `/testindex/logs` that your mapping type is called `logs` and not `loginevent`

Comment: Hi Val, thank you for your input. I have dropped the index, modified the index template by copying and pasting the new mapping. However, i am still getting the same error
    "Invalid format: \"2016-12-12 21:31:13\" is malformed at \" 21:31:13\"

Comment: That's weird, it works well for me on ES 2.3. Which version are you running?

Comment: Well, it even works without the quotes around the space character... Are you sure you have a real space character between the date and the time and not a tab or some other weird whitespace character?

Comment: 100% Positive that there is not a funky char in the space between the yyyy-MM-dd and HH:mm:ss

Comment: Val, i think i may have found the problem. At the beginning of my mapping declaration i am using "loginevent" rather then "_default_". Is it possible this may be causing the error? What do i need to add to the curl command to have it match the loginevent type?

Answer (score 0):

So i found out what the issue was. At the beginning of my mapping file i had defined a custom type (non *defualt*). This was throwing off my curl command. I wasn't adding a type.

The relevant mapping config from my index template.

```
"mappings": {
  "loginevent": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "event_time_utc": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "format": "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        "type": "date"
      }
```

Updated curl command

```
 curl -k -XPOST 'http://10.1.69.191:8080/testindex/loginevent' -d '{
```

Successful Execution

```
{"_index":"testindex","_type":"loginevent","_id":"AVj-UoW23y1afHQdnQA-","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}
```